# Нажатие на кнопку "Вход", поверх которой открывается форма

Tags: javascript, html

Приветствую! Необходимо создать страницу, где посередине была бы одна кнопка "Вход", нажав на которую ПОВЕРХ неё появилось бы окно, куда надо вводить "логин" и "пароль". Скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом сделать всплывающее окно для ввода данных при нажатии кнопки "ВХОД" ?

Comment: Берёшь IDE или, хотя бы, блокнот, браузер и пишешь.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос про верстку всплывающего окна, то примерно так:
html:

```
<div id="btn" onclick="showWindow()">Вход</div>
<div id="content_window">Тут форма</div>
```

css:

```
#btn{
 position:absolute;
 top: 50vh;
 left: 50vw;
 z-index:1;
}
#content_window{
 position:absolute;
 height:100vh;
 width:100vw;
 z-index:10;
 background:lightgrey;
 display:none;
}
```

js:

```
function showWindow(){
  var el = document.getElementById("content_window");
  el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

А если вопрос про создание работающей формы логина с клиентской и серверной частью, то он довольно широк и правильный ответ - ботать прогу, либо поискать готовое решение)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте, например, basic auth:[Описание на вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Upd: поясню. Делаете статичную страничку, на ней кнопка ВХОД. По нажатию на кнопку - делаете переход на страницу в защищенной зоне.